# iAd show in the timeline

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, iad, timeline

Is it possible to use the iAd of Apple and show not at the top or at the bottom, but use the ads in your timeline. Like Facebook sponsor or twitter sponsor. So you show them in the timeline. Is this possible? I use phonegap to build the app btw.

Comment: If you are using cordova, your timeline will be html, so no, you can't display a native view between too html elementis displayed on the same webview, you can just show them over the webview.

Comment: okay. thanks for your answer.